# Javascript Switch case keeps returning NaN value

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm still new to Javascript, switch statements, and other programming concepts. My problem is whenever I try to access case 2 it keeps returning NaN instead of an integer value or number. Are my arguments invalid in console.log()? Or am I using my switch statement incorrectly?

```
const constantVol = (num, T1, T2, P1, P2) => {
  let choice = num;
  switch(choice){
    case 1:
        choice = (T2 / T1) * P1;
        break;
    case 2:
        choice = (P2 * T1) / P1;
        break;
    default:
        choice = "Not valid"
        break;
  }
  return choice;
}

console.log(constantVol(num=2, P2=16.33, P1=3.4, T1=296.5));
```

Comment: P2 is undefined.  undefined in a math operation returns NaN

Comment: Also you can't use named parameters like that in Javascript

Comment: You passed 4 arguments, so the 5th argument is undefined

Comment: I just want to note that this question could actually help a lot of newbs.  Albeit if it were worded better.  I'm sure there are a lot of programmers from languages with named parameters getting confused, because Javascript gives enough flexibility in its syntax that the code still runs, but doesn't keep its intention because (in this case) named parameters aren't supported in Javascript.

Comment: To the guys from Python or whatever language with named parameters, what is happening here is that `(num=2)===2` `(T1=296.5)===296.5`, so `constantVol` ends up with `P1===296.5` and `P2===undefined` (was not passed a value).  Javascript as of today does not have named parameters.  The closest you can get to named parameter syntax is object destructuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we don't have named parameters in Javascript, but we can use object destructuring to sort of simulate similar syntax.
I am passing an object map with names as one parameter into the function {key: value}, and then using destructuring to grab from the properties into the named variables var [key]=value.

```js
const constantVol = ({num, T1, T2, P1, P2}) => {
  let choice = num;
  switch(choice){
    case 1:
        choice = (T2 / T1) * P1;
        break;
    case 2:
        choice = (P2 * T1) / P1;
        break;
    default:
        choice = "Not valid"
        break;
  }
  return choice;
}

console.log(constantVol({num: 2, P2: 16.33, P1: 3.4, T1: 296.5}));
```

Comment: He's trying to use named parameters.  Probably coming from Python or something.  `=` or passing parameters in order doesnt match his intention

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `=` sign.  Javascript just happens to allow variable assignment to return the value assigned in its syntax so the parameter is being sent through as the parameter in each position.  He just needs to know that we don't have named parameters in Javascript.

Comment: No, you edited it later and kept the syntax even in your answer, in a way that even with the edit still doesn't properly explain what he was confused about.  And then commented here that the function would still work with the `=`, when clearly it would not have, because he was passing them out of order trying to use named parameter syntax.

Comment: Ya, but it's still wrong and additionally misleading.  If you actually understood what was happening you would be using the same syntax without the `=` sign to highlight the problem, but are instead claiming that "if you use`=` the parameters must be in order".  It clearly has nothing to do with whether he uses `=` or not.

Comment: Ya, okay.  You went and edited your comment to add in "passing them in the right order" and then claimed that was "exactly what you said", conscendingly I might add.  And then to make matters worse edited that into your answer yet are _still_ claiming in your answer "if you use `=` the parameters must be in order".  It has nothing to do with whether he uses `=` or not and is plain misleading.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function you need to send values to all parameters and in the correct order. Here the function constantVol is expecting 5 values and you are only sending 4. Also, they will be read in the order they are passed it does not matter if you add the variable when you are calling it. 
So when you call

```js
    constantVol = (num, T1, T2, P1, P2)
```

with

```js
    console.log(constantVol(num=2, P2=16.33, P1=3.4, T1=296.5));
```

You get:

```js
    num = 2 
    T1 = 16.33
    T2 = 3.4
    P1 = 296.5
    P2 = undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not that experienced with JacaScript as well but
your code looks like you are not giving it a value for P2?

But I just saw you want to go for case 2..
but if you do the math you will go to default case because the result is not 2